# Why Java configuration doesn't create databases, tables in databases in MySQL automatically?

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot

Currently, I am developing a web application using Angular, Spring boot, and MySQL. I need to create and update databases and tables automatically in MySQL. But My computer didn't create databases also automatically and gave a backend error as "unknown database db". Then I created the database manually. Then the backend builds properly but still doesn't create tables.

Application properties code:

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

customer.java code:

```
package com.Manipulus.arctic.customer.model;


import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false,updatable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "nic_number" )
    private String nic_number;

    @Column(name = "customer_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "contact_number")
    private int contactNumber;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "contact_person_name")
    private String contactPersonName;

    @Column(name = "designation")
    private String designation;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false,updatable = false)
    private String customerCode;

    public String getCustomerCode() {
        return customerCode;
    }

    public void setCustomerCode(String customerCode) {
        this.customerCode = customerCode;
    }

    public Customer(){

    }
    public Customer(String nic_number, String name, int contactNumber, String address, String contactPersonName, String designation, String email,String customerCode) {
        this.nic_number = nic_number;
        this.name = name;
        this.customerCode =customerCode;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.address = address;
        this.contactPersonName = contactPersonName;
        this.designation = designation;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getNic_number() {
        return nic_number;
    }

    public void setNic_number(String nic) {
        this.nic_number = nic;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getContactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }

    public void setContactNumber(int contactNumber) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getContactPersonName() {
        return contactPersonName;
    }

    public void setContactPersonName(String contactPersonName) {
        this.contactPersonName = contactPersonName;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Customer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                "nic_number=" + nic_number +
                "name=" +name +
                "contactNumber=" +contactNumber +
                "address="+ address +
                "contactPersonName="+contactPersonName+
                "designation="+ designation +
                "email="+email+
                '}';

    }


}
```

CustomerResource.java code:

```
    package com.Manipulus.arctic.customer;

import com.Manipulus.arctic.customer.model.Customer;
import com.Manipulus.arctic.customer.service.CustomerService;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerResource {
    private final CustomerService customerService;

    public CustomerResource(CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> getAllCustomer(){
        List<Customer> customers = customerService.findAllCustomers();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(customers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/find/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> getCustomerById(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
       Customer customer = customerService.findCustomerById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(customer, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> addCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer){
        Customer newCustomer = customerService.addCustomer(customer);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newCustomer, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PutMapping("/update")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> updateCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer){
        Customer updateCustomer = customerService.updateCustomer(customer);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(updateCustomer, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }


    @DeleteMapping ("/delete/{id}")
    public void deleteCustomer(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        customerService.deleteCustomerById(id);
    }



//        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);


//    @DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
//    public ResponseEntity<Map<String,Boolean>> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable long id){
//        Employee emp = emp_repo.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not exist with id: "+id));
//
//        emp_repo.delete(emp);
//        Map<String,Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
//        response.put("Deleted",Boolean.TRUE);
//        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
//    }

}
```

Java Version that I use is 18. My frontend or backend doesn't show any kind of error while compiling or running. But on the interface of the web application it shows "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/customer/all: 0 Unknown Error"
I think My backend doesn't connect with MySQL properly. and also I am a beginner. So I request to help me to solve this error.

Comment: `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG` put this in the config and check for logs if there are some errors

Comment: Change once `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` this to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`

Comment: Once the database is created with first run; for the next run on; you need to change back this property too :
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

Comment: Could you update your question to provide code for your 'customer/all' endpoint. Will make finding root cause easier.

Comment: To me your code looks good. Could you update the "/all" endpoint to ```return null```. And check if you're able to get a 200 OK response on Postman. This way we can know whether the issue is occurring on database or not. When making requests from client you must set up CORS. So please also add @CrossOrigin under @RequestMapping. But I don't believe this will resolve this issue yet, if you're getting 404.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA will not create a database for you. You must ensure the database exists before running the application, hence you must create it manually. This is why you're seeing "unknown database db" error.

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

The above config will make hibernate check the difference between your entity and schema in **already existing database**. If any difference is found, updates will be made to your table. This also includes creation of a new entity to be saved in your database.

---

Regarding your second issue

> Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/customer/all: 0
> Unknown Error

Do you have a REST endpoint created for this endpoint? Could you double check the server is running and the endpoint URL is also correct. I would recommend you download a tool called Postman, which provides a quicker way to test your API endpoints.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  already used postman and it gives {
    "timestamp": "2023-03-24T04:14:16.903+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/customer/all"
}kind of error